# How do I tell if my phone has Carrier IQ Software on it?

Tags: malware, carrieriq

What is known about the [Carrier IQ Software](http://www.androidpolice.com/2011/11/29/how-deep-does-the-rabbit-hole-go-an-in-depth-look-at-carrier-iq-the-data-it-logs-and-whats-really-going-on/) and Android handsets?  I see a similar icon as shown on the Carrier IQ app next to an app called "Contact Data" and another called "Contact Sync". Does my phone come with Carrier IQ?

Comment: The icon is a default icon, not specific to Carrier IQ.  It can't help you determine whether or not CIQ is present.  The article is slightly misleading on that point.

Comment: On my Bionic, there are two programs, EACH WITH THE SAME ICON AS CARRIER IQ, Contacts Sync and ContactsData. These also cannot be removed....

Answer (score 22, accepted):

On your phone's home launcher, go to menu --> settings --> applications and look for anything that contains "Carrier IQ", "IQ", or possibly "com.carrieriq.iqagent"

**If you are rooted,** it appears that [this app](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=17612559&postcount=110) will check and see if it exists on your phone.  The [paid license key](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.treve.loggingkey&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS50cmV2ZS5sb2dnaW5na2V5Il0.) will also let you remove it from your phone. This app was made by Trevor Eckhart, the person who discovered this "vulnerability."

**If you are not rooted,** [this app](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.projectvoodoo.simplecarrieriqdetector) will attempt to detect Carrier IQ on your phone. And [here is another app](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.lookout.carrieriqdetector), by Lookout, that will detect for Carrier IQ on your phone.

**Also: if you are rooted and running a custom OS, such as CyanogenMod,** you should have no worries about Carrier IQ. Carrier IQ is bundled by the manufacturer/carrier and shouldn't be included in a ROM such as CyanogenMod *as long as it is built from the [AOSP](http://source.android.com/) and is not a derivation of a manufactuer's ROM.*

Comment: I've also heard it may simply be "hidden".  I'm still researching and will update my answer accordingly

Comment: And, per your answer here (http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/16352/is-htc-iqagent-a-version-of-carrier-iq/16353#16353), it may appear under another name, such as HTC IQAgent.

Comment: Some "Custom" ROMs are modified versions of the stock firmware that shipped with a device. Those may contain CarrierIQ if the ROM author did not/could not remove it.

Comment: @broam Thanks, I clarified that better in my post

Answer (score 5):

The people who make Lookout now have [Carrier IQ Detector](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.lookout.carrieriqdetector) available in the Market.

*Note*: It just detects it. It does not offer any tools to remove it (for which you would need root anyway).

Answer (score 4):

Verizon claims that their phones are [Carrier IQ-free.](http://www.theverge.com/2011/12/1/2602532/verizon-carrier-iq-denial)

Comment: Their privacy policy seems to indicate they do some form of data collection, but they may do it network-side.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution from the [Lookout Forums](https://support.mylookout.com/entries/20728287-does-lookout-check-for-carrieriq). This solution uses an App from the Android App Market, and is easier to install then the "Logging Test App". The Logging Test App doesn't work on my phone (Samsung Intercept).

1. Install [Any Cut](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.appdroid.anycut&hl=en) from the Android App Market. "Any Cut allows you to create Home shortcuts to anything!"
2. Go to "Activities". This will create a list of possible shortcuts on your system. It might take a minute for the list to appear.
3. Look for apps named 'IQRD' and/or 'IQAgent'.