# Is HTC IQAgent a version of Carrier IQ?

Tags: htc, carrieriq

Some HTC phones have a service called HTC IQAgent.  Is this the same as the Carrier IQ software?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, [HTC IQAgent is Carrier IQ software.](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1051593)

Comment: More info here: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/16315/how-do-i-tell-if-my-phone-has-carrier-iq-software-on-it/16317#16317